# Parallel sort of generic linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, parallel-processing, java-8

I have a generic linked list: let's say `LinkedList<Comparable> cl` in a method. How can I sort this linked list in parallel? `Collections.sort()` can't do parallel. The closest thing I can do is do unchecked casts to and from Object, using `Arrays.parallelSort()` in between, but that throws a `ClassCastException` due to Java's apparent inability to manage generic arrays.

**How can I sort a generic linked list in parallel?**

---

What's more, it seems that loop copying works, while list joining doesn't. Why?

**Note:** this is after a sequential sort.

I just ended up settling on this:

```
for (Object o : poolarr) {
    pool.add((O) o);
}
// can't do pool.addAll((O[]) Arrays.stream(poolarr));
```

I guess it's that age-old array cast problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't get much parallelism out of a linked list in any case, because you can't easily decompose it.  So you could do:

```
list.parallelStream().sorted().collect(toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

But I doubt you'll see a lot of benefit from doing that in parallel, because the only option for decomposing a linked list is (first, rest), which is not going to produce a nicely shaped computation tree.

Alternately, you could:

```
Comparable[] elems = list.stream().toArray(Comparable[]::new);
Arrays.parallelSort(elems);
```

Which entails an O(n) copying cost but then the sort will parallelize nicely.

Comment: Remember that I am sorting a linked list of a generic. It doesn't really work so well. Also, linked lists are not that much slower to sort because `sort` methods put them into an array first.

Comment: Wait --- it's actually an `ArrayList`, but the question still stands.

Comment: @Simon Kuang: the first solution *does* what you are asking for. `list.parallelStream().sorted()` applied to a linked list will internally copy items into an array and invoke `Arrays.parallelSort`. If you insist on modifying the original `List` you can use `Collections.copy(List,List)` afterwards.

Comment: Brian, I'm surprised that you write the answer.